# What would happen if I never met a valkyrie in God of War PS4 game?

Tags: ps4, god-of-war-2018

In the God of War PS4 game, at the end after spreading Faye's ashes and returning from Jötunheim, as part of character story play Atreus asks if we could free other dragons or Valkyries. The only way Atreus knows about them is when we discover Odin's hidden chambers. If a game player never opened these/visited any Valkyries would Atreus still know about them?

Comment: Isn't there at least one hidden chamber that you will have to visit as part of the main story ?

Comment: actually there is no chamber that mandates you to visit in the story, all of them are optional. And there is a youtube video where a user tried to reach a valkyrie before resurrecting mymir, Kratos and atreus didn't know what it was